# Package Python project along with dependencies to another machine without internet and different OS

Tags: python, pip

As the title suggests, I have a computer running mac os with a python project. I so have a windows computer without internet, with Python 3.6, and with pip.

The project in question relies on a couple pip package dependencies. Is there anyway to package everything together so that the project can work on the windows machine with no internet?

Comment: how are you getting the package on the windows machine if you don't have Internet

Comment: @aws_apprentice on windows I already have pip and python 3.6, on mac I have the project with the dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **some extent** `pip` allows to download a package with dependencies for a different platform. Try

```
pip download --only-binary=:all: --platform win_amd64 --implementation cp --python-version=3.6 --abi=cp36m 'put-your-package-name-here'
```

If the package and all its dependencies provide binary wheels `pip` downloads all of them into the current directory. Move them to the offline computer and run there

```
pip install --find-links=\path\to\wheels\directory 'your-package'
```

If the package and all its dependencies provide only source distribution try

```
pip download --only-binary=:none: --platform win_amd64 --implementation cp --python-version=3.6 --abi=cp36m 'your-package'
```

But if the package and dependencies are mixed — some have binary wheels and some only sdists — `pip` fails to download dependencies. There is no solution for this situation. The only workaround is to run Windows on your MacOS — in an emulator or a container.

PS. I use platform `win_amd64` as an example. If you have 32-bit Windows or if you have 32-bit Python on a 64-bit Windows — use platform `win32`.

Comment: I would have chosen to first build a requirments with ```pip freeze > all_reqs.txt``` and convert to wheels with ```pip wheel -r all_reqs.txt``` and afterwards download everything with your approach for whl that are not ```any```

Comment: Run `pip freeze` on MacOS to list Windows packages? What's the point? Convert packages on MacOS to OSX wheels to be moved to Windows? Isn't that a bit meaningless?

Comment: No it is not, as a lot of packages will be ```py2.py3-none-any.whl``` which will run/install under most if not any python version and os (pure python).

Comment: IMO there are not so many universal packages. Most now have extension written in C/C++. Some are almost completely written in C/C++. People usually need numpy, scipy, pandas, tensorflow.